# 'npm run build' gives no error but 'npm start' gives error

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I had previously executed `npm start` without any errors on the exact same code. Since the last time I had executed it without any errors, I had made no changes to the files. But just a day later, the same code suddenly gave this error:

```
> client@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I can't understand why this happened. However, `npm run build` compiles without any errors and generates the build properly. So I don't think it is some issue with the code.

Further, I ran `npm install` once again, I found that there were some vulnerabilities:

```
added 684 packages, removed 193 packages, changed 411 packages, and audited 1873 packages in 2m

153 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

32 vulnerabilities (19 moderate, 12 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

So, following the instruction I used `npm audit fix --force` and I saw it updated `react-scripts` to version 5.0.0 . This suddenly solved the previous error and the code compiled without errors after this, however, now I faced another problem.

On visiting `localhost:3000` it showed `localhost refused to connect`, even though my terminal showed that the code was compiled successfully.

This is the project in which I encountered the error: https://github.com/DevRish/martcart.

I have also opened an issue regarding this: https://github.com/DevRish/martcart/issues/1

I am confused about two things here. Firstly, with `react-scripts` version 4.0.3, why is build compiling without errors but development environment giving error? Secondly, even when `react-scripts` version 5.0.0 compiles the code successfully, why does localhost:3000 show 'refused to connect' ?

Answer (score 0):

Update: After removing the setupProxy.js file, it works fine.

I added the proxy attribute in the package.json file to achieve the proxying functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).